# Can i use django.db.transaction.atomic with ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: python, django, multithreading, transactions, django-database

I have a large set of Projects to validate and update with transaction in 1 perform. If 1 project failed it need to rollback all projects. but when i use ThreadPoolExecutor it got stuck with no log ERROR or WARNING even with max_workers=1.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, wait

@transaction.atomic
def update_projects()
    projects = Project.objects.filter(...)
    items = [(project, auth) for project in projects]

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=MAX_WORKER) as executor:
        futures = [executor.submit(validate_and_update, *item) for item in items]
        wait(futures)

def validate_and_update(project, auth):
    # get other data and validate with project. 
    project.save()
```

i tried multiprocessing instead of threading but it got other error like:
"no results to fetch"
"pop from empty list"

```
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=2)
    for item in items:
        pool.apply_async(validate_and_update, *item) 

    # close the pool
    pool.close()
    # wait for all tasks to complete
    pool.join()
```